# Close event of optionspage in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome Extension by using manifest version 2. i have an option page like google explains here (open_new_tab is set to false)

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2

the settings on my options page give a live preview on their impact. everything works fine. but when the user closes the option page i want to undo unsaved changes. however i cannot find any close event. how can i get notified when the user closes the option page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to detect that an extension page has closed is to maintain an open [`Port`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-Port) with it obtained through `chrome.runtime.connect`/`onConnect` API.

You can establish a connection to another script that does the live preview and listen to `onDisconnect` event on the Port object. Don't forget to store the reference to the port somewhere on both sides or it will be garbage-collected and disconnected.